# Toolbar back button hidden because of start destination

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

### Background

I am trying to use one activity per module where each activity has its own nav graph. So the navigation goes from activity in one dynamic-feature module to another activity in another dynamic-feature module.

**Feature1/ActivityA -> Feature2/ActivityB**

ActivityA just calls basic `startActivity` method to launch ActivityB.

#### Problem

Since `ActivityB` technically has its fragment at start destination. It doesn't shows up the back button even though I have my `ActivityA` in my backstack. Is there any way to get around this issue?

PS: Since `ActivityA` & `ActivityB` are in 2 separate module I am avoiding to have them under one graph. For activity transition I am just calling `startActivity` by creating `intent` using `className`.

**Update** - Even if I use nav controller to navigate from ActivityA's fragment to ActivityB, The issue still exists.

#### ActivityB.xml

```
</layout>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_back"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:title="@string/title" />

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/host_container"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/landing_graph" />
    </LinearLayout>

</layout>
```

#### ActivityB.kt

```
internal class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var navController : NavController? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val toolbar = binding.mainToolbar
        navController = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.host_container) as NavHostFragment).navController
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener { onBackPressed() }
        toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

#### landing_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:startDestination="@id/blankFragment">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment"
        android:label="Blank"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/blankFragment2"
        android:name="com.example.cashdog.cashdog.BlankFragment2"
        android:label="Blank"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank_2" />
</navigation>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using separate activities when Navigation [specifically supports dynamic feature modules in a single graph](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-dynamic)?

Comment: with dynamic-feature modules deep-links are not supported, that's the main reason.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [AppBarConfiguration guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui#appbarconfiguration), if you want the Up button to appear on all destinations, even your start destination, you should use the `AppBarConfiguration` constructor that takes a list of top level destinations. By passing an empty set, every destination will show the Up button.

Therefore you ActivityB should be:

```
internal class ActivityB : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var navController : NavController? = null
    private val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(emptySet())

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val toolbar = binding.mainToolbar
        navController = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.host_container) as NavHostFragment).navController
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)
        // You must always use setupActionBarWithNavController
        // when using setSupportActionBar()
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        return navController.navigateUp(appBarConfiguration) || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the issue happening with passing `emptySet` is that `android:label` for the start destination doesn't get picked up the first time when startDestination fragment is loaded. Feel the only workaround is to call `setTitle` from startDestination Fragment when it is loaded.

Comment: The set of top level destinations is not used in determining the behavior of whether the label is set (it is always set, for every destination). Sounds like you have some other issue going on.

Comment: If I don't pass `emptySet` then the title shows up without the back button because it picks the `android:label` from the navigation graph but when I pass `emptySet` it picks my app name as the label.

Comment: Personally, I don't see any reason why you'd have `app:title="@string/title"` on your toolbar in the first place if you're using `android:label` in your graph. Even given that, as per [the source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:navigation/navigation-ui/src/main/java/androidx/navigation/ui/AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java;l=85), the title is unconditionally set, no matter what set you pass in.

Comment: I am changing `title` dynamically i.e trying to keep one activity per feature module. So, a single activity can have different navigation graphs(aka different start destinations). I will use `setTitle` via fragment as a workaround. Thanks for the help really appreciate it.

Comment: i think emptyset solved the issue .Ty